# How would I spoof/open a com port from a microcontroller to a device with multiple ports?

Tags: microcontroller, usbserial

I have a device which receives/outputs IrDA commands as well as receiving serial LED data from a product. Normally it plugs into a computer and a rx/tx tool specifically made for this function has a GUI which opens one available port for IrDA and one for serial data rx.

I've got the device powered and it's usb lines running into an ESP32, which I thought would have the output from the LED serial on them, but nothing is coming through. I imagine I need to "open" a specific one of the COM ports available on the device from the ESP32, but am stuck on how to do that.

How could I open a specific COM port for a device from an ESP 32?

I tried scoping the wires to see if there's any packets or different outputs coming from the device, but to no avail.

Comment: so you have some host or other computer and you want to access the esp32 as a "com" port?   you need firmware on the esp32 that makes the usb look like a virtual com port then.  usb is usb, to make it look like a keyboard, or mouse or com port or thumb drive you need to support the right protocol in the code running on the esp32.  then if you want the esp32 to also do some led thing or irda thing that is outside the esp32, then the esp32 firmware also needs to support that interface on its other I/O pins.

Comment: are you doing all of that?